# close all powershell sessions on machine

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I've created a huge API which allows calling powershell from C#.

I've handled quite a few things automatically, but i seem unable to handle powershell sessions properly upon a crash. Which results in at somepoint i will be utterly unable to connect to the WINRM service on a remote PC.

Is there a way to get ALL remote sessions? i know

```
Get-PSSession
```

But it only gets all remote sessions in the current session, and that's practically useless to me.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with `Get-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -State All`?

Comment: Well I've tried a bunch of different varieties, and they don't seem to function everytime. Furthermore, even if I can get the sessions they don't always seemed to be removed when parsed to remove-pssession

Comment: Well, you might try `Invoke-command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {Get-Process} -InDisconnectedSession`, but that's any disconnected session, or you might try using WMI to restart the WinRM service.  Neither of those is foolproof.

Comment: Well doesnt quite seem  like any of my options are then :(